# Mockito: How to easily stub a method without mocking all parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I have a method i'd like to stub but it has a lot of parameters.
How can i avoid mocking all parameters but still stub the method.

Ex:

```
//Method to stub
public void myMethod(Bar bar, Foo foo, FooBar fooBar, BarFoo barFoo, .....endless list of parameters..);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't quite follow what problem you're having using Mockito.  Assuming you create a mock of the interface that contains your `myMethod()` method, you can then verify only the parameters to the method that you are interested in.  For example (assuming the interface is called `MyInterface` and using JUnit 4):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MyInterface myInterface = mock(MyInterface.class);
    FooBar expectedFooBar = new FooBar();        

    // other testing stuff

    verify(myInterface).myMethod(any(), any(), eq(expectedFooBar), any(), ...);
}
```

You'll need to do a static import on the Mockito methods for this to work.  The `any()` matcher doesn't care what value has been passed when verifying.

You can't avoid passing something for every argument in your method (even if it's only NULL).

Comment: I guess he really wants to call myMethod(), so he needs to pass all those parameters every time which bloats the test.

Comment: I'm testing a controller and i'm stubbing my service method. the service is mocked. I guess the any() should work. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

use mockito.any

if myobj mymethod accepts string, string, bar for instance

to stub a call

```
Mockito.when(myojb.myMethod(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(Bar.class)))
    .thenReturn(amockedobject);
```

to verify SteveD gave the answer already

```
Mockito.verify(myojb).myMethod(
    Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(Bar.class)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a wrapper class which calls the real method and fills in all the arguments but the ones you supply (a.k.a "delegation").

And at the next opportunity, file a bug against the project asking to move the parameters to a config object.

Comment: True - too many parameters on a method signature is a bad code 'smell'.

Comment: I'm having 5 parameters, and yes they are needed:) It's a service method i'm trying to stub. I only wanted to be theoretical for methods where you don't really want to stub the parameters

Comment: The problem with "a million" arguments seems to be a very common problem with many SOAP services. #fail

Comment: @Michael Bavon: The question isn't "Are they needed" but the fact that the poor human brain gets easily confused when it has to get five parameters right. Especially when they are all strings... :-) Google for "builder pattern" for a nice and simple solution.