# Mockito: When is not working if predefined Search Criteria is passed to dao and service having dao is called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

`service.searchRaashanRegister` contains another method `adresseDao.findRaashan(crit)` for which should return particular result for parameter `setUnit` `"BUBBA"`

```
  SearchResult<Raashan> searchResult = new SearchResult<Raashan>();
  searchResult.setSize(1);
  searchResult.setResult(Arrays.asList(raashan));

  SearchCriteria crit = new SearchCriteria ();
  crit.setUnit(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("BUBBA")));
  crit.setPage(0);
  crit.setPageSize(15);
  crit.setSort(null);
  crit.setQuery("");
  crit.setSortAsc(Boolean.TRUE);

  when(raashanDao.findRaashan(crit)).thenReturn(searchResult);

  //This request is sent to web service from which above criteria is created.
  RaashanSearchRequest searchRequest = new RaashanSearchRequest ();
  searchRequest .setPage(0);
  searchRequest .setPageSize(15);
  searchRequest .setUnit("BUBBA");
  searchRequest .setQuery("");
  searchRequest .setSort(null);
  searchRequest .setSortASC(Boolean.TRUE);

  RaashanResponse response = service.searchRaashanRegister(searchRequest );
```

The above code is not giving desired results and `adresseDao.findRaashan(crit)` is returning `Null`. When I use `any(SearchCriteria.class)` then test pass okay but we want results on particular critera.

I also added initMocks in @Before:

```
@Before
public void init() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Unable to get what is reason where error occurs.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You want to have all **relevant** code in your question, instead of giving further bits as comments on answers. The question needs to stand on its own, having all the things in it we need to answer it. This clearly doesn't

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, I think you need to use `eq` matcher -`org.mockito.Matchers.eq` if planning to set expectations on specific instances.

I am assuming `raashanDao` is a mocked instance , so it would be like ,

`when(raashanDao.findRaashan(eq(crit))).thenReturn(searchResult);`

**UPDATE :** For previous discussion, I think, I misunderstood your question. `eq(crit)` should work as is in `when` as well as in verify without setting anything since that is a method parameter.

A sample is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340801/mockito-how-to-easily-stub-a-method-without-mocking-all-parameters)

You use `any` for parameter values that you don't care and use `eq` for specific values.

Comment: eq(crit) does not work. I do not understand (need to set same crit instance to your raashanDao mocked instance too). In @Before we already have service class initialized having above mocked object as parameter

Comment: Code is like 

@Before
   public void init() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      service = new RaashanServicesImpl(RaashanDao, manlingDao, quatroDao);

   }

Comment: crit is criteria argument inside findRaashan method -> raashanDao.findRaashan(crit). It is an object having various arguments as shown in above snippet

Comment: That is why your `any` matcher works since you are not bothered for specific instances. You will not be able to use `eq` unless you change your code to have some way to set that `crit` . All in all, value used `eq` should be available when actual method call happens. There are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146131/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-sabir-khan).